# STM32 M4 Cortex WAV Player SD Card DMA DAC

Tags: stm32, wav, dma, dac

For months I try to run a wave file 16bit 48kHz from SD Card to my DAC output via DMA.

But all I get is scary sounds. I read so many ST Electronics data sheets, but nothing solve the problem.

First I try HAL Driver, but only a sine waveform from an array worked. Not the wave file.

So I switched to Low Layer drivers for DMA, TIM6 and DAC.

Here my init source in main:

```
  LL_DAC_EnableDMAReq(DAC1, LL_DAC_CHANNEL_1); // enable DMA for Channel1
  LL_DAC_Enable(DAC1, LL_DAC_CHANNEL_1); //enable Channel on DAC
  LL_DMA_ConfigAddresses(DMA1, LL_DMA_STREAM_5,(uint32_t) &DAC_Buff, LL_DAC_DMA_GetRegAddr(DAC1, LL_DAC_CHANNEL_1, LL_DAC_DMA_REG_DATA_12BITS_RIGHT_ALIGNED ), LL_DMA_DIRECTION_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH ); //Speicherbereich auf den die DMA Unit zugreift definieren
  LL_DMA_SetDataLength(DMA1, LL_DMA_STREAM_5, 2);     // die beschreibung in UM1725 ist heir etwas dürftig ich hab einfach mal 16 für 2byte genommen
  LL_DMA_EnableIT_HT(DMA1,LL_DMA_STREAM_5);     // Halb Transfer Interrupt für Sream5 aktivieren
  LL_DMA_EnableIT_TC(DMA1,LL_DMA_STREAM_5);      // Complet Transfer Interrupt für Sream5 aktivieren
  LL_DAC_EnableTrigger(DAC1, LL_DAC_CHANNEL_1);  // ohne geht garnix, aber wenn an muss man __disable_irq machen
  LL_DMA_EnableStream(DMA1, LL_DMA_STREAM_5);    //Stream5 DAC1 Starten
```

My source to read the file worked:

```
char wave_playback(const char *FileName)
{
  FRESULT res;
  FIL file;
  UINT cnt;
uint32_t filesize;

  res = f_open( &file, FileName, FA_READ );   //file oeffne
  if(res) return 1;
filesize= f_size(&file);
  res = f_lseek(&file,0x2c);                  // WAV head  überspringen
//  filesize=filesize-0x2c;
  if(res) return 2;
 f_read (&file,&DAC_Buff[0],512,&cnt);       //beider 256 Buffer befüllen
 //filesize=filesize-512;
  if(res) return 3;

 __disable_irq();

  //TIM6->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;
 LL_TIM_EnableCounter(TIM6);                // Timer 6 der DMA triggert starten

  while(1)
  {
     volatile ITStatus it_st;
         it_st = RESET;
     while(it_st == RESET) {   //auf Flag für halben Transfer warten
         it_st = LL_DMA_IsActiveFlag_HT5(DMA1);
         //it_st = READ_BIT(DMA1->HISR ,DMA_HISR_HTIF5);
     }
     f_read (&file,&DAC_Buff[0],256,&cnt);      //unteren buffer befüllen
     LL_DMA_ClearFlag_HT5(DMA1);                // half transfer flag (stream5) löschen
    // DMA1->HISR |= DMA_HISR_HTIF5;
    // filesize=filesize-256;
     if(cnt<256)break;                        //wenn das ende des files erreicht while verlassen

     it_st = RESET;
     while(it_st == RESET) {   ////auf Flag für kompletten Transfer warten
     it_st = LL_DMA_IsActiveFlag_TC5(DMA1);
     //it_st = READ_BIT(DMA1->HISR ,DMA_HISR_TCIF5);
     }
     f_read (&file,&DAC_Buff[256],256,&cnt);  //oberen buffer befüllen
     LL_DMA_ClearFlag_TC5(DMA1);  //complet transfer flag (stream5) löschen
     //DMA1->HISR |= DMA_HISR_TCIF5;
    // filesize=filesize-256;
     if(cnt<256)break;                        //wenn das ende des files erreicht while verlassen
  }

  //TIM6->CR1 &= ~TIM_CR1_CEN;                  // Roh Kommando Timer 6 der DMA triggert stoppen
  LL_TIM_DisableCounter(TIM6);                  // Timer 6 der DMA triggert stoppen

  f_close(&file);                             //file stream beenden

  return 0;                                   //bei wenn i.O. 0 zurueck geben
}
```

I checked twice the wave files on the SD card (16bit 48kHz) But the sound is scary and I don't understand why.

Then I try it again with HAL Drivers but there nothing works so I switch back to LL Drivers.

What did I do wrong? Dose anybody know it?

Comment: You didn't precise what kind of hardware you're using (eval board). I assume there is a speaker somewhere ? Which one and how it is connected with the STM32 ? Usually you can find example source code to demonstrate the different functionalitites of an eval board. it is the case for STM32 Nucleo and EVAL boards. Did you check that ?

Comment: It is a STM32F4xx_M DevEBox Board V3 with a STM32F407 VGT6 ARM microcontroller. It is not an official Development board from ST. The offical example source from ST for there board don't helped me at all.  

2DAC DAC1 at PA4 an DAC2 at PA5 Pin.

Comment: Like this one. [link] (https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a312a.7700824.w4004-5253464463.7.b5ce5dffCtsoYr&id=582677940441)

Answer (score -1):

Likely you have a bit or byte endian issue in the data you're playing. Try switching to 8-bit mode:

```
LL_DMA_SetPeriphAddress(DMA1, LL_DMA_STREAM_5, LL_DAC_DMA_GetRegAddr(DAC1, LL_DAC_CHANNEL_1, LL_DAC_DMA_REG_DATA_8BITS_RIGHT_ALIGNED));
LL_DMA_SetPeriphSize(DMA1, LL_DMA_STREAM_5, LL_DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE);
LL_DMA_SetMemorySize(DMA1, LL_DMA_STREAM_5, LL_DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE);
```

Comment: what is bit endian?